# How to make Java class run on startup using Context Listener without affecting other scheduled tasks?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, initialization, servletcontextlistener

I am using Eclipse in Apache Tomcat server to execute my java based web project.

I have to run a function written in the class, "socket.java" only once, when application starts. I tried to initialize this class, i have other scheduled tasks running on other thread implemented by other servletContextListner. When i run this 'Socket.Java' on ServletContextListner, then the application is not working properly. Now the scheduled tasks on other ServletContextListner is only running once.

How to solve this?

my Listener class is as below,:-

```
package com.my.classes;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class SocketContextListner implements ServletContextListener{

    private Executor Task;
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Task= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();      
        Socket b = new Socket();
        Task.execute(b);
    }
}
```

---

The other ServletContextListener with many scheduled task, which is not running when i implemented the Context listener for Socket

```
package com.my.classes;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class JMonitorContextListner implements ServletContextListener{

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler1;
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scheduler1.shutdownNow();
//      System.out.println("Context1 Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      System.out.println("Context1 initialized"); 
        scheduler1 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Jmonitor(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FeedStatus(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AutoReset(), 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduler1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AutoLogoff(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
```

### }

My web.xml file:

```
<listener>
<listener-class>com.my.classes.JMonitorContextListner</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.my.classes.SocketContextListner</listener-class>
</listener>
```

---

My Console:
[image]

console print such as The priority,  ip from db and Null point exception are supposed to print again and again as it is from the scheduled task

Please suggest me, how to initialize the class "Socket.java" without affecting the normal working of application?

When i created separate listener for Socket.java and executed it on a different thread, my scheduled tasks on "JMonitorContextListner" stops after first run. Why is it happening?

Suggestion and any piece of code is highly appreciated.

Comment: When i run the program, then the scheduled tasks run once and stops. Why? how to solve this?

Comment: What is the code of Socket? What is the code of your other processxxx classes (and why don't you respect the Java naming conventions)?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry, i'm a beginner to programming. The Sokect.Java class is implemented with runnable. and the code is:-  public void run() {
  int a=1;
  dbLayer dbrst = new dbLayer();
  int j = dbrst.sockserv(a);
 }

Comment: @JBNizet The Socket java class initialize a function written in another class. The other classes also have similar function to this but i want this to run only once at the initial. I'm sorry, if i sound any disrespect.

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question, not in comments. But of course, since you have a single thread for all your scheduled tasks, if one of them, as I suspect, waits forever on a socket, then no other task can be executed, since the unique thread is blocked waiting on the socket.

Comment: @JB Nizet Sir, You are right. Thanks. I have updated my question.I just want it to run only once. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @JB Nizet You are right, i have created a dedicated Context Listener for Socket.java to run and now the Tomcat is stops at the initialization of the program. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Listen to the socket from a separate thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132619/discussion-between-jasim-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: @JB Nizet I tired it, then the tomcat is not running properly.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't care about what you're doing in your specific thread, that it doesn't even know about. If you have a specific problem, then post a minimal, complete example reproducing the problem, and explain the problem precisely.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated my question as suggested by you.

Comment: You're still not listening to the socket in a separate thread, and there is no stack trace that would explain where the NullPointerException comes from.

Comment: @JBNizet NullPointerException is result of function from a scheduled task, and it was there long before, not affecting program. I'll add separate thread for socket.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated my question, now the Socket run on separate thread but the scheduled tasks on other context listner  are only running in the beginning

Comment: One of them is probably blocking the unique thread, once again.

Comment: @JBNizet The socket is initialized by Task, "Task= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();" it is a separate thread, right? How is it possible for this thread to block the "scheduler1"- thread of other context listener?

Comment: You said: "JMonitorContextListner stops after first run". All the tasks are executed by a single thread. If one blocks, it prevents all the other ones to execute. The very first question I asked is "What is the code of your other processxxx classes". You still haven't posted their code.

Comment: @JBNizet Dear Sir, The question will become too big, if i post all those codes. Four other processxxx classes run four different functions in dbLayer.java which includes database access. Yes i said, "JMonitorContextListner stops after first run", all the tasks are executed by single thread. So let me check by individually stopping each task which is executed in the single thread

Comment: @JBNizet  Dear Sir, i found the process which is not working, it is the FeedStatus the function is depended on the input from ClientSocket. Thank you Very much

Comment: @JBNizet So, running the specific function, Feed Status on a separate thread will solve the problem, right? If you can write this solution as an answer, i can put tick mark for you.